# Does the Java main method start an infinite while-loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, main-method

This question might be a really newbie one, but it's pretty confusing to me. I'm working on Java networking, and I'm curious as to the back-end of the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

I understand it that the `main` starts one thread?  So even if I have a simple "Helloworld" program, a thread stays alive until you close the whole IDE or system?

Does that mean I can include any arbitrary code in the main method, which I want to run forever too( for example, a heartbeat sensor check or some other checks).

thanks

Comment: The JVM doesn't stay alive unless a non-daemon thread is continuing to run, and this won't occur unless the coder explicitly or implicitly (such as running a Swing GUI) creates one or somehow keeps the main non-daemon thread alive (such as with a while loop).

Comment: But remember again that some libraries if started can create and have a non-daemon thread running, such as the Swing library as I've noted above. I'm sure that there are other examples of this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - OK cool - so starting a Swing GUI creates a non-daemon thread. I'll study-up on this! thank you!

Comment: The non-daemon thread only starts if you make the GUI visible, and care must be taken to make these calls on the Swing event thread only (via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`). If your primary purpose is not to create a Swing GUI, then I wouldn't use this at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The JVM starts a thread (the main thread) and executes your main method inside this thread. As soon as the main method returns, if there is no other non-daemon thread running, the JVM exits.

You can run an infinite loop in the main method, and the JVM will never exit (unless it's killed from the outside).

Comment: Understood - so the JVM will automatically exit if no non-daemon threads exist .  thanks!